# When making technically minor changes, should i create a new user story or update an existing (closed) story?

Tags: user-stories, change-management

I am working with a team that is maintaining case management software. We are suffering from drift between different specifications, agile artefacts, implementations and understandings. I would like to propose a solution to the team that aligns with agile methodologies that works for our team.

Frequently, we will get a request to "show additional data X about entity Y on screen Z", where X may be an existing or new field/property, and Y and Z are almost always an existing entities / screens.

There would have already been a user story that has long been closed:
`As a user ... I want to see information ABC about entity Y so that I can ...`, which would have been used to create the screen in the first place.

Typically `field X` would just be another piece of information that is not important in itself, but is important when in the context of `entity Y`. I would find it hard to justify having a story purely to see `field X`, and other stories typically look at collections of data, not single datums.

Should I:

1. Create a new story `As ... I want to see X about Y so that I can ...` - this keeps closed stories closed, and means smaller, more incremental stories, but also means that the old story is no longer current, so I can't treat it as part of the documentation.
2. Re-open the old story and update the acceptance criteria `As ... I want to see ABCX about Y so that I can ...`, and then create a task `Add field Y to Z` - this means that stories, tasks (and other artefacts) are all up to date. Typically, the
3. Some other solution? Perhaps use a feature/epic/whatever to track `screen Z`, and keep that up to date with all the fields about entities that `screen Z` would display, and then use method 1 and reference the feature?
4. Something completely different?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/20526/defect-found-in-previous-iteration-bug-or-new-work

Comment: Just link the new story to the old story. That link should show up in the old story as well, so it remains "current".

Answer (score 7):

You should not reopen an old story. You should create a new one and if it is in any way connected to the old one, you could put a link to the old one in the new one.

New requirements are completely new work and add new value to the Product, so definitely go with the new Story.

Comment: Couldn't add anymore to this. It's one of the few places in agile development that is pretty much cut and dried. Done is done. If you buy a pickup truck from the dealer and then a year later want to get the tow package, that's a new purchase. Same logic with User Stories.

Comment: Beside of full support of this answer I recommend to also *highlight the parts of original story acceptance criteria which became obsolete*. It would save time in the future for sure. (Don't update, just highlight or put couple of words.)